# How to populate Recycler view one by one when user touch anywhere on screen?

Tags: java, android

I want to populate recyclerview items when user click anywhere on the screen one by one. Eg on first touch load first item on second touch load second item on third touch load third item and so on. I have no idea how to implement this.

Here is my adapter code

Adapter

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.ViewHolder>{

        List<MessageModel> list;
        Context context;

        public MessageAdapter(List<MessageModel> list, Context context) {
            this.list = list;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
           View view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                   .inflate(R.layout.chatbubble, viewGroup, false);
           ViewHolder myHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

            return myHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
            MessageModel model = list.get(i);
            if(model.getSender().equals("left")){
                viewHolder.left.setText(model.getText());
                viewHolder.right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.middle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else if(model.getSender().equals("right")){
                viewHolder.right.setText(model.getText());
                viewHolder.middle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                viewHolder.middle.setText(model.getText());
                viewHolder.left.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.right.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            TextView left, right, middle;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                left = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_incoming);
                right = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_outgoing);
                middle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_middle);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Activity` which holds your `RecyclerView`, do the following code changes.

1. Add an `onClickListener` or `onTouchListener` whichever you prefer to your `RecyclerView`.

   `recyclerView.setOnClickListener()` or `recyclerView.setOnTouchListener()`
2. Add the code to add the items into your `RecyclerView` in above event listeners.

   yourList.add("Your Item");
   adapter.notifyItemInserted(int positionAtWhichItemWasInserted);

   adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

   //For some reason I'm unable to format the above code snippet.
3. Make sure you call `notifyItemInserted()` OR `notifyDatasetChanged()` after you add the item in your RecyclerView list.

Comment: i m adding data dynamically to the list

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem. This'll all happen after the data is fetched.

Comment: thanks it worked with ````ontouchlistener```` with little modification